# Верно, что в первом варианте нужна запятая, а во втором не нужна?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1. Я(,) когда домой пришла, он уже высох.
2. Я(,) когда домой пришла, то он уже высох.

Comment: Разговорное сокращение от: *Я, когда домой пришла, увидела, что он уже высох.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях запятая не нужна.

***Я когда домой пришла, он уже высох.***

***Я когда домой пришла, то он уже высох.***

А если еë поставить, то местоимение **Я** автоматически не входит в придаточную часть, зато входит в главную, а такая структура некорректна, то есть, если поставить, получится:

*Когда домой пришла, **я он** уже высох*;

*Когда домой пришла, **я то он** уже высох*.

Выглядит некорректно, так что запятые ставить нельзя, первое местоимение обязательно входит в придаточную часть.